# Output Multiple Files with JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have a software built in Java swing, and I need to output a metadata file in addition to the file that the user exports. I am able to export either the data file or the metadata file individually, but I keep having trouble outputting both at the same time. I know JFileChooser has `chooser.setSelectedFiles()` and `chooser.getSelectedFiles()` for such purposes. Could someone please show me how to use them properly? The following is the code I have tried (but they don't work):

```
File[] outputFiles = new File[]{
        new File(fileName+".txt"),
        new File(fileName+"_metadata.txt")};

exportChooser.setSelectedFiles(outputFiles);

int returnVal = exportChooser.showDialog(null, "Export");
if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
    File[] files = exportChooser.getSelectedFiles(); 
......
}
```

some other code here...

```
try{
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(files[0]));
    writer.write(d, format, out);
    out.close();
    BufferedWriter md_out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(files[1]));
    List<String> metadata = d.getAgilentMetadata();
    for(int i=0;i<metadata.size(); i++) {
        md_out.write(metadata.get(i));
        md_out.write("\n");
    }
    md_out.close();

}catch(Exception e){...}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, lets assume for a moment that what you actually need is only one file, from there you can "append" the meta name to that file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, instead of trying to specify two files, while to just prompt for one and then apply the (extension and) meta name part to it?

Then you could do something like...

```
int returnVal = exportChooser.showDialog(null, "Export");
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File file = exportChooser.getSelectedFile();
    File path = file.getParentFile();
    String name = file.getName();
    if (!name.toUpperCase().endsWith(".txt")) {
        name += ".txt";
    }
    String metaName = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf("."));
    metaName += "_metadata.txt";

    File outputFile = new File(path, name);
    File metaFile = new File(path, metaName);
}
```

*nb: You may need to make your own decisions about how to handle possible existing extensions, I just made it a requirement to end in `.txt`*

Then you can just write the contents out something like...

```
try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile))) {
    // Write stuff...

    try (BufferedWriter metaBW = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(metaFile))) {
        // Write meta data
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

IF, you MUST be able to select the meta data file separately (which to me makes no sense, because then how do you associate the two files together?), you will need to check the number of selected files returned by the `JFileChooser` and verify that you have the expected/required number of files

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you so much! But just for learning purposes, how are .setSelectedFiles() and .getSelectedFiles() actually used? When should they be used?

Comment: That would depend on requirements.  `set/getSelectedFiles` are used when you have the need to process multiple files